# Jquery not receiving input in utf-8

Tags: jquery, input, utf-8

I am using this code to get submitted value and it is unable to give me the value, instead saying `undefined`

Here is my code:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function() {
    var keyword = $("#key").attr("value");
    alert(keyword);
});

    <div id="page-wrap">
        <input type="text" id="key" dir="rtl" lang="ar" /> 
        <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
    </div>
```

Now if i search for `'رمضان‬‎'` alert is returning `'undefined'` , would love to hear similar alternates for this `$("#key").attr("value");`?

http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/qvwMw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attr("value")` gets the value of the `value` attribute from the HTML markup.
If our `input` had a `value` attribute present, 
`$("#key").attr("value");` would return that value.

Either use `prop("value")` or the `.val()` method

```
var keyword = $("#key").prop("value");
```

or

```
var keyword = $("#key").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't want the `.attr('value')`, but `.val()` instead.
It doesn't have anything to do with encodings, "ASCII" doesn't work just the same.

Comment: An *attribute* is an attribute (`value=""`), the *value* is the current input value.